# program crashes if image is not found in the folder,but it should record in log- logging issue

Tags: python, logging

my program crashes if that particular image is not found in the image folder.The program looks for image in the image folder and imagecolumn in the csv.If the imagename is present in the imagecolumn  but not found in the folder ,then it crashes. i tried to log the imagefile,but failed.

This is I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil                       # making a duplicate copy of a file
import logging
from os.path import splitext        # splits name & extension from a file


class Image:

    def image_fix(self):

        # logging
        LOG = "example.log"
        logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',
                            filemode='w',
                            format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)


        # console handler
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        logging.getLogger("").addHandler(console)


        # using panda to open and read csv
        df = pd.read_csv('rgw.csv')
        df['Image'] = df.ImageName + "_" + df.ImageWChain + ".jpg"

        #checking if column "ImageWChain" has "jpg" extension,then concat .jpg
        if ".jpg" not in df.ImageWChain:
            df['ImageWChain'] = df.ImageWChain + ".jpg"

        if ".jpg" not in df.ImageName:
            df['ImageName'] = df.ImageName + ".jpg"

        # write to csv
        df.to_csv('rgw.csv')
        old_image = df.ImageName
        new_image = df.Image

        #splits the imagename and extension
        for item in enumerate(old_image):
            name, ext = splitext(old_image[item[0]])
            if (ext == ""):
                continue
            oldFileName = name + ext
            print("oldFileName = " + oldFileName)
            newFileName = new_image
            print("newFileName = " + newFileName)

            #checks whether image file exits in folder or not
            if (os.path.isfile(oldFileName)):

                #creates duplicate copy of an image
                for old_image, new_image in zip(df.ImageName,df.Image):
                    shutil.copy2(old_image,new_image)

            else:
                # if image not found in folder,then stores in log


                logging.info(oldFileName)

                # write into log
                logger = logging.getLogger(oldFileName)
                logger.debug(" <- This image was not found in the folder")


if __name__=="__main__":
    obj = Image()
    obj.image_fix()
```

The traceback is

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/New/a.py Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "D:/New/a.py", line 23, in <module> shutil.copy2(old_image,new_image)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2 copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R0056SS.jpg'
```

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Do you get an error message? If so please share it.

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe D:/New/a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/New/a.py", line 23, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(old_image,new_image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R0056SS.jpg'

Comment: How is this problem related to logging ? Do you expect the logger to automagically catch exceptions and log them ???

Comment: As a side note: the way you use the loggin module is just a complete mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
       #checks whether image file exits in folder or not
        if (os.path.isfile(oldFileName)):
```

You are testing the existence of `oldFileName`, but then trying to copy `old_image` :

```
            #creates duplicate copy of an image
            for old_image, new_image in zip(df.ImageName,df.Image):
                shutil.copy2(old_image,new_image)
```

Comment: i am trying to check if the image exists in the folder and csv column if not then write in log